# Comparing an array to a single string output using assertEquals in Java

Tags: java, junit, tdd

So I would like to create a simple code that greets people according to the input.
The difficulity I have that I have no idea how to compare a simple string with an array, using arrayEquals (or any equivalent).
This is the way I have created the code - according to a previous project:

***Test file:***

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class test {
    @Test
    public void ShouldGreet() {
        assertEquals("Hello, my friend.", new GreetPeople().greeter(""));
        assertEquals("Hello, Bob.", new GreetPeople().greeter("Bob"));
    }
}
```

***Actual code:***

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GreetPeople {
    public String greeter(String[] names) {
        if (Arrays.stream(names).count() == 1) {
            return("Hello, " + names + ".");
        }
        return("Hello, my friend.");
    }

}
```

Any kind of help is well appreciated!

Comment: The code you showed should not have compiled. `greeter` takes an array. You can't pass a string to it.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: So in my actual code the ```greeter``` function expects an array to be passed. I want to make my ***test file*** pass an array to test. I have already tried declaring an array and inserting it into ```assertEquals``` however I couldn't get it to work so I have decided to restore my code to the original state before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first patameter of greeter is an array:

```
    assertEquals("Hello, my friend.", new GreetPeople().greeter(new String[]{""}));
    assertEquals("Hello, Bob.", new GreetPeople().greeter(new String[]{"Bob"}));
```

Comment: My output gets messed up using this, however the error itself is now fixed, so thanks! :)


`Hello, [Ljava.lang.String;@6b71769e.` is my new output.

Comment: @FábiánBalázs that is because you doing `"Hello, " + names + "."` and just trying to print the whole passed array via String concatenation. Going by the code it looks like you are trying to print the first element of the passed array, which would be done with `"Hello, " + names[0] + "."`

Comment: `Arrays.stream(names).count()` - what the.. just write `names.length`.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't go onto change that one!
Thanks! ;-)